# Title bar tab active with Bootstrap in XPages

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, titlebar

I'm starting a new xpages project, and I'm going to use the bootstrap. I will use application Layout with responsive bootstrap configuration. I will use the 'Title bar' property. I'm doing tests but I have not found a solution to keep the active tab of the active title bar highlighted with another color. What happens is that when clicking on a certain tab of the title bar, it changes color, for the color defined for active tab, however, when I select any option in the navigation bar, the link to the color set for the tabs not selected. I have already tried using the navigationPath property, which works with OneUi layout, but with no bootstrap. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How about you write your own layout custom control? That will give you full control over everything. Every time I started with the application layout control, I had to do that at some point because I wanted to do something that was not (or not good enough) supported.

Comment: Do you have any sample templates?

Comment: Go to the Bootstrap site and find the template you need (e.g. with a fixed header/footer. You can then copy the source to a new custom control and use that for starters.